# Run Bash command from PHP 7.0

Tags: php, linux

I've been trying to run the php script:

```
shell_exec("bash  /etc/example.sh")
```

from the browser but it does not work. This bash file creates a new one on the /etc directory.

I've also tried the functions `exec() && system()` but they don't work either. The weird thing happens when I run other Linux commands on these php function like:

```
shell_exec(rm -r /etc/fake);
```

they work fine, I have also tested my bash file on the linux command line and it works great.

I am sure this is not a permission issue, since I previously set the 777 permission on the file i am trying to execute.

```
shell_exec("bash  /etc/example.sh")
```

I am using php7.0.33 and Debian 9, so I suppose this may be an issue with this PHP version 7.0.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: does whatever php is running as have permission to create a directory in /etc ?

Comment: yes do you need help?